# innerHTML not working in IE 9 but working fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, innerhtml

```
<script>
function add(memid) {
var likedcount=document.getElementsByName("liked"+memid);
for (var i = 0; i < likedcount.length; i++)
  {
likedcount[i].innerHTML = parseInt(likedcount[i].innerHTML)+1;
  }
 }

</script>

<b name="liked123">5</b>
<b name="liked123">5</b>

<b name="liked123">5</b>

<input type="button" onclick="add(123);" value="add">
```

the above works for FF but for some reason IE doesnt?

Comment: What are you using innerHTML on? (like, what element?)

Comment: You would need to see exactly what innerHTML is in this case.  Probably it's slightly different which is throwing off your parseInt.  Or perhaps getElementsByName is returning different results.  This sounds like you should be doing some basic debugging and collecting of information before asking us.  You can at least put some breakpoints in and look at the state of variables or put an alert in to see what state things are in.

Comment: the element is <b name=likersnumber123>50</b>

Comment: Please try innerText instead of innerHTML and see what happens.

Comment: What **does** happen in IE?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Are you sure that "threadlikecounts.length" is not zero?

Comment: you are right length is 0, but why does this code work in FF and not IE??

Comment: problem is with the ("liked"+memid) how do i add a variable to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the  tag does not define a "name" attribute this will not work.  [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that tags that don't natively support the name attribute (ie the attribute is an "expando"), do NOT get returned from getElementsByName.

Comment: what should i use to replace <b> then ?

Comment: Are all of the items currently with name='liked123' grouped inside a container?  Then you could grab the container (by id eg) and operate on all of its <b> tags.